# Oracle query same table by differnt ID and display 6 columns per row

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to query the same table for 6 items with different ID. ideally I would like to have a resultset as

column1 colum2 colum3 colum4 colum5 colum6

I am trying with this query but I wonder if there is a better way to do it

```
SELECT *  FROM
   (
   SELECT
   numeric_value as SMBP 
   FROM  HALO.T_MEAS_VALUE
   WHERE 
   MEAS_ASS_ID IN(100002)
    AND value_dtime >= TO_DATE('2020-05-01 04:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
   AND value_dtime < TO_DATE('2020-05-31 04:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
   ) A ,

 (
  SELECT
   numeric_value as SMTT
   FROM  HALO.T_MEAS_VALUE
   WHERE 
   MEAS_ASS_ID IN(100003)
    AND value_dtime >= TO_DATE('2020-05-01 04:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
   AND value_dtime < TO_DATE('2020-05-31 04:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
   ) B;
```

the sexpected output should be this

[image]

After applying @lalit Kumar response I now use this query

```
SELECT
meas_ass_id,
value_dtime,   
CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100004  THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END as SMBP,
CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN ABS(numeric_value / 29.3071) END as SMTP,
CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 AND numeric_value <0 THEN 'BUY' ELSE 'SELL' END as BUYSELL,
CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN ABS(numeric_value /29.3071) END as TDAY,
CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100003 THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END as SAP,
CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100066 THEN ABS(numeric_value /29.3071) END as TDAY2
 FROM  HALO.T_MEAS_VALUE
   WHERE 
   numeric_value IS NOT NULL   
   AND MEAS_ASS_ID IN(100002,100003,100004,100066)
    AND value_dtime >= TO_DATE('2020-05-01 04:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
   AND value_dtime <= TO_DATE('2020-05-31 04:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
   ORDER BY value_dtime ;
```

and I have this result
[image]

How I can get rid of all NULL values now?

**EDIT**

After applying aggregation I get only one row (I guess this is because of MAX )

```
SELECT
MAX(meas_ass_id),
MAX(value_dtime),   
MAX(CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100004  THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END) as SMBP,
MAX(CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN ABS(numeric_value / 29.3071) END) as SMTP,
MAX(CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 AND numeric_value <0 THEN 'BUY' ELSE 'SELL' END) as BUYSELL,   
MAX(CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100003 THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END) as SAP,
MAX(CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100066 THEN ABS(numeric_value /29.3071) END) as TDAY2
 FROM  HALO.T_MEAS_VALUE
   WHERE 
   numeric_value IS NOT NULL   
   AND MEAS_ASS_ID IN(100002,100003,100004,100066)
    AND value_dtime >= TO_DATE('2020-05-01 04:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
   AND value_dtime <= TO_DATE('2020-05-31 04:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
   ORDER BY value_dtime ;
```

[image]

**EDIT 3**
By using this query

```
    SELECT
    meas_ass_id,
    value_dtime,   
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100004  THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END ) as SMBP,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN ABS(numeric_value / 29.3071) END ) as SMTP,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 
              AND numeric_value <0 THEN 'BUY' ELSE 'SELL' END ) as BUYSELL,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN ABS(numeric_value /29.3071) END ) as TDAY,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100003 THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END ) as SAP,
MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100066 THEN ABS(numeric_value /29.3071) END ) as TDAY2
 FROM  HALO.T_MEAS_VALUE
   WHERE 
   numeric_value IS NOT NULL   
   AND MEAS_ASS_ID IN(100002,100003,100004,100066)
    AND value_dtime >= TO_DATE('2020-05-01 04:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
   AND value_dtime <= TO_DATE('2020-05-31 04:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
   GROUP BY meas_ass_id, value_dtime
   ORDER BY value_dtime ;
```

I get this result

[image]

Comment: I added the output

Comment: Is that the output from my query? As I don't see the columns I asked you to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: just added "edit 3", see screenshot... still null values around; I may end up using one query per each needed value but I really do not like the idea to go back and forward f= to the database with 6 queries for the above

Comment: Then you should remove `meas_ass_id` from select and group by clause because you are already showing them in different columns.

Comment: by removing 'meas_ass_id'  is perfect!!  tahnk you

Comment: Great! You're welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need 6 case expressions to display as 6 columns:

```
SELECT
    value_dtime,   
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100004  THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END ) as SMBP,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN ABS(numeric_value / 29.3071) END ) as SMTP,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 
              AND numeric_value <0 THEN 'BUY' ELSE 'SELL' END ) as BUYSELL,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN ABS(numeric_value /29.3071) END ) as TDAY,
    MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100003 THEN ABS(numeric_value *29.3071) END ) as SAP,
MAX( CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100066 THEN ABS(numeric_value /29.3071) END ) as TDAY2
 FROM  HALO.T_MEAS_VALUE
   WHERE 
   numeric_value IS NOT NULL   
   AND MEAS_ASS_ID IN(100002,100003,100004,100066)
    AND value_dtime >= TO_DATE('2020-05-01 04:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') 
   AND value_dtime <= TO_DATE('2020-05-31 04:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
   GROUP BY value_dtime
   ORDER BY value_dtime ;
```

Comment: please see my last question ; I just need to get rid of teh NULL values now

Comment: @brillox So what do you expect in case of NULL, should it be zero?

Comment: no should not be 0, these null values should be discarded so that for each day I ahve one single value for each colum

Comment: Okay, then you need to aggregate the rows using `MAX`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100002 THEN numeric_value END) as SMBP,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MEAS_ASS_ID = 100003 THEN numeric_value END) as SMTT,
       . . .
FROM HALO.T_MEAS_VALUE
WHERE value_dtime >= TIMESTAMP '2020-05-01 04:00:00' AND
      value_dtime < TIMESTAMP '2020-05-31 04:00:00';
```

Note the use of `TIMESTAMP` to introduce literal date/time values with a time component.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I also added your suggestion for using TIMESTAMP